# React native useState not working with real time firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, use-state

inside getRoomData function setRoomInfo not working? How can i fix it? I can't see data from joinGame.

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
const [roomInfo,setRoomInfo] = useState([]);
        function getRoomData(){
        const roomID = room;
        database()
        .ref(`rooms/${roomID}/`)
        .on('value', snapshot => {
            const list = snapshot.val();
            if(list!=null){
                console.log("getRoom:"+list.roomid)
                const r = list;
                setRoomInfo(r);
            }
        });
    }
    function joinGame(){
        console.log(roomInfo);
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        getRoomData();
    },[])
```

Comment: Where are you calling `joinGame` from ?

Comment: I call it using button